# Important concepts of BigQuery DWH

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-functions

I wanted to know like which concepts/topics I need to learn in order to work for a BigQuery DWH project? Along with Big Query, what other programming languages I need to get acquainted or expertise with(like python)? I am currently working as data enginner with ssis, informatica, power bi skills with strong sql. Please give your valuable suggestions.

Thanks,
Ven.

Answer (score 0):

BigQuery has an SQL interface so if you don't already know SQL, learn it.

See the query [reference](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/query-syntax).

Also, you can interact with BigQuery using Bash, with the `bq` CLI provided as a Google Cloud component in the `gcloud` CLI, or with Python, Go, Java, node.js... (choose your favorite).

Actually if you are not planning a long term project, or become an expert of BigQuery, the more complex concepts are not needed. In case you want to know more about it I link a pretty interesting [blog](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/gcp/bigquery-under-the-hood).

To sum up:

- Learn SQL
- Take into account that BigQuery is optimized for reading and performing analysis, it is not a common database (do not exceed with writes)
- Most common languages has a bigquery client, so you don't need to learn any new language.